# Perl and curses library - exit from a child thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, ncurses

```
sub worker {

    # Curse stuff
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    my $fh = FileHandle->new;
    open $fh, q{-|},
        "$myexe @pre_args make @after_args 2>&1"
        or croak 'Cannot open';
    process_output($fh);
    my $err = close $fh;

    endwin();
    return;
} 
sub process_output {
    my ($fh) = @_;

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        #do stuff
    }
}
ReadMode 3;
threads->create(\&worker);
while (threads->list(threads::running)) {
    my $char = ReadKey -1, *STDIN;
    if ($char) {
        if ($char eq 'q') {
            endwin();
            kill('INT', $$);
            threads->exit();
        }
    }
}
ReadMode 0;

foreach my $thr (threads->list) {
    $thr->join();
```

When I press 'q':

```
Perl exited with active threads:
        1 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

and then I did `ps -fu myuserid`

I saw that `$myexe` was still running

Q1) How can i force child process to exit? threads->exit() didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious problem with the sample program is that it is using multiple threads for the curses library.  That won't work.  (curses is not thread-safe).  If you have to do this, keep all of the curses work in the same thread.

Comment: all the curse work is in the same thread. at least writing to the screen portion. its happening at process_output subroutine. $myexe provides just bunch of lines. it doesnt do any curse work. and the parent thread just read keyboard inputs

Comment: My comment was mainly about Q2 (screen messed up).  If endwin is not called, curses will not even try to restore the terminal modes -- sounding like the symptom.  However the Q1 appears to say that this branch may not even have been called.  Reading the script, it seems some detail may have been omitted, so it's hard to analyze further.

Answer (score 1):

You call `exit` but don't `detach` or `join` the threads.

Stick:

```
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() ) { 
    $thr -> join;
}
```

at the end, and your 'main' code will wait for your threads to (all) exit.

However - `threads -> exit()` is for exiting the *current* thread. See: 
http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#EXITING-A-THREAD

In order to terminate another thread, you need something like `threads -> kill`. Either send a 'proper' kill signal, or use a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` or similar.

I'd probably approach it a little differently though - define a shared variable:

```
my $done : shared;
```

And then test it within the while loop, so you've a normal execution flow rather than a mid flight `kill`.

Your `kill ( INT, $$ )` is going to be killing your *main* process, and just drop the threads on the floor. That's not good style really.

So - to backtrack a bit - the problem you're having - I think - is because 'signals' in perl aren't what you're expecting them to be. Perl uses safe signals, which makes a blocking call (such as a read from a filehandle) block the signal.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29

So I wouldn't normally suggest using signals within threads are a good idea - they're a little erratic, which isn't good for program predictability.

You can 'throw' and 'catch' signals, by defining a signal handler within the thread:

```
 $SIG{'USR1'} = sub { print "Caught USR1"; die };
```

And then 'call' it using:

```
 $worker -> kill ( 'USR1' );
```

But in certain circumstances, that won't 'bail out' immediately in the way you expect.

For example - this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;

sub worker {

   print Dumper \%SIG;
   my $tail_pid = open ( my $tail_proc, "-|", "tail -f /var/log/messages" );
   $SIG{'USR1'} = sub { print "Caught USR1\nKilling $tail_pid"; kill ( 'TERM', $tail_pid ); die; threads -> exit() };

   print "Pre-loop\n";

   while ( 1 ) {
       print "Thread processing\n";
    sleep 1;
   }
    print "Done";
   return;
}

my $worker = threads -> create ( \&worker );

sleep 2;
print "Sending kill\n";
$worker -> kill ( 'SIGUSR1' );
sleep 2;
print "waiting for join\n";

$worker -> join();
```

But if your while loop is reading from the file handle - it's a blocking call, so the 'kill' will be held until the block lifts.

E.g.

```
while ( <$tail_proc> ) {
```

Will go into a block pending IO, and your thread won't 'get' the signal until IO occurs, and the thread continues processing. That *might* be sufficient for your needs though. Otherwise you're potentially looking at `select` or `IO::Select` to test if the handle is readable.

So what you *may* want to do instead is just kill the process that's 'feeding' your while loop - because by doing so, it'll unblock and the `while` will become `undef` and exit.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $kill_pid : shared;

sub worker {
   $kill_pid = open ( my $tail_proc, "-|", "tail -f /var/log/messages" );
   print "Pre-loop\n";
   while ( <$tail_proc> ) {
       print "Thread processing\n";
       print;
    sleep 1;
   }
    print "Done";
   return;
}

my $worker = threads -> create ( \&worker );

sleep 2;
print "Sending kill\n";

if ( defined $kill_pid ) { print "killing tail, $kill_pid\n"; kill ( 'TERM', $kill_pid ); };
sleep 2;
print "waiting for join\n";

$worker -> join();
```

Comment: how can i force child thread to exit right away? it seemed like the child thread didnt get the SIGINT signal

Comment: `threads -> kill` should do it. But I'd be tempted to suggest instead, create a shared variable and test that in your while loop.

Comment: Actually. Given opening an exec handle, you could use the returned pid from that as something to kill.

Comment: OK, I think I've got something - basically - if you kill the results of your `open` from your `main` thread, your while loops `break`. See example in code.